# Convert video from FFMPEG than video is rotated

Tags: php, api, video, ffmpeg

I have created one Application API, in this Application API When i have upload video from file manager than video is rotated but when i have capture and direct upload than video is perfect work.

i have use this command   `transpose=1` but capture video is rotated 90 degree when upload and if i have remove this command than file manager video is rotated.

so please give me solutions.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' -s 640x1280 -b 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output_video.mp4
```

file manager upload video is auto rotated on 270 degree, i have not use any rotated command but capture video is work perfect.

Comment: Recent `ffmpeg` will automatically rotate the video if the input has rotate sidedata. Since you provided no console output from your command there is no way to verify if your input contains such data. So either let `ffmpeg` automatically rotate, or add `-noautorotate` if you want to do it manually.

Comment: i have use -noautorotate but video is not play.

Comment: "not play" could mean too many things to pinpoint your actual issue. For example, I could respond with "your player is broken". Lazy questions get lazy answers. Seriously, you need to provide useful info. Your actual, unscripted `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output/log is required if you want help.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard my player is not broken but when i have add watermark than video auto rotated on 270 degree but if i can't add watermark than it's work perfect.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' -s 640x1280  -b 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output_video.mp4`

Comment: Please do not try to cram everything into a comment. You should [edit] your question to include your command **and the complete console output**.